# Passing functions without () into map/filter/reduce

Tags: python-3.x, generator

In Python3.X, when passing methods into Map/Filter/Reduce, why is it done without '()'? Does this apply to all generators?

This is probably a simple question but I can't find a clear answer in docs. I'm hoping to understand the reasons rather than just "memorizing" syntax.

e.g.

```py
map(str.upper, ['a', 'b', 'c']) #this works 
vs 
map(str.upper(), ['a', 'b', 'c']) #this gives an error
```

Comment: Signature of map is `map(func, *iterables)`. First argument is a function. `str.upper` is a function (<built-in method upper of str object at 0x1053b9670> if you do `>>> help(''.upper)` in REPL). str.upper() will take action on str and returns an upper case copy. To satisfy map's arguments, you'd provide the function str.upper not the result of the upper function.

Comment: Thanks @zedfoxus, this was very practical insight for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confusing at first, especially when you come from other programming languages. In Python the functions are objects and you can pass them along without invoking them. Check below example:

```
def func():  # function definition
    print("func was invoked")


a = func  # assign func object (without invoking it)
print(a, type(a))


a()  # invoking the function
```

`map` will use this function object to invoke the function for each item in the iterable.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why it would be more confusing if you come from other programming languages. Python is far from being the only language having higher order functions (in fact, almost all modern programming languages have them), and far from being the language that uses the most this feature.